# Float element right to max-width

Tags: html, css

In a responsive layout I want to show the logo in the header on the right side but only up to a certain width. But the background of the header should extend to the whole width of the page. If the viewport is smaller than the "maximum width" the logo should of course still be visible.

I can achieve this with a wrapper, but I would like to know if someone has a way of avoiding the wrapper. Maybe with some flexbox or grid magic.

Here's a working example with a wrapper, the JS is just there to simulate the user resizing the browser window:

```js
// Simulate the user resizing the browser window:
const min = 300;
const max = 1000;
let width = min;
let add = 1;

setInterval(() => {
  document.querySelector('header').style.width = width + 'px';
  width += add;
  if (width > max) {
    add = -add;
  }
  if (width < min) {
    add = Math.abs(add);
  }
}, 1);
```

```css
header {
  background: blue;
}
header::after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  clear: both;
}
h1 {
  float: left;
}
.logo {
  float: right;
  background: white;
}
.wrapper {
  max-width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h1>Pagetitle</h1>
    <div class="logo">Logo</div>
  </div>
</header>
```

I would like something that works with this markup (the real code has some more elements in the header):

```
<header>
    <h1>Pagetitle</h1>
    <div class="logo">Logo</div>
</header>
```

Comment: As you mentioned, you can achieve this with flexbox. There are also other ways, such as making use of the Bootstrap framework. F.eks. making use of the row and col classes.

Comment: what is your desired output. Can you explain it in one line

Comment: @Viira I added some JS to my working snippet to simulate the user resizing his browser window. The output is what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `flex`, `flex-shrink` `flex-grow` properties. Here are some useful links:

- [Flex Property: w3 schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp)
- [Flex Shrink: mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink)

And here is the working example:

```css
header {
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
 }
h1 {
 flex: 0 2 450px;
}
.logo {
  flex: 0 2 50px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Pagetitle</h1>
  <div class="logo">Logo</div>
</header>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work for my specific use-case because there are too many other items with unknown width in the header. But it does address the use-case from the question, so I will accept the answer.

Comment: Actually, while being a little more permissive with the width of everything and a little calc magic I managed to make it work, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here a simple solution using `flexbox`

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  display: flex;
}

.logo {
  margin-left: auto; /* Pushes it as far to the right as possible. */
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Pagetitle</h1>
  <div class="logo">Logo</div>
</header>
```

Comment: The problem is that the logo shouldn't be as far to the right as possible. It should only be to a maximum of 500 px to the right.

Comment: And that's what exactly it does @BjörnTantau. Check the result.

Comment: the answer he provided is correct, use add margin:0 auto; to header to see it works fine

Comment: But then the header itself does not expand to the full width.

Comment: In the question and the simulation, its clearly written and visible 'But the background of the header should extend to the whole width of the page.'